# Query gets modified when sending via ajax to datatable processing file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm sending the following query from php to other datatable processing file but it gets changed, i tried to alert the generated query it gets alerted properly but when i echo it on the processing php file its different

Query which is send via ajax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM xyz 
WHERE xyz_service = 'xyz' 
  AND (yzx_order_no like ' %123% ')  
ORDER BY xyz_id DESC
```

And the above query gets modified to the below one

```
SELECT * 
FROM xyz 
WHERE xyz_service = 'xyz' 
  AND (yzx_order_no like ' 123% ')  
ORDER BY xyz_id DESC
```

**%** gets removed.

ajax code:

```
var sql = <?php echo $sql; ?>   
"ajax":{
              url :"xyz_response.php?sql="+sql, // json datasource
              type: "POST",  // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE

            },
```

just sent to the url file and echoed on that page

Comment: Sending a complete query via AJAX seems to me to be a Very dangerous this to do. It means you have an API sitting waiting to run ANY query that gets sent to it. Like one that deletes all the tables. Or one that let a hacker list all the user accounts and emails and credit card details etc etc

Comment: But back to the question, please show us HOW you are AJAXing this string to the API

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the suggestion, but the page just accepts the generated queries from the specific pages and direct access to the file is blocked

Comment: @user3783243 by POST

Comment: This is your actual code or pseudo? I'd think `sql` assignment would need to be quoted.

Comment: you'd need to urlencode the sql (since you send it as get parameter) _and_ put it in quotes.